# How to get a dynamically generated web page in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

As part of my discovery of web scraping, I'd like to browse and get all of my Strava activities. I'll use the profile of Thibaut Pinot as an example. I'm using Python 3 and Requests.

On the [user's page](https://www.strava.com/pros/1603067), one can see every of his activities, but not all at once. Indeed, they are chronologically sorted, so you have to use a timeline. You can then choose to display activities weekly or monthly and choose the period of time: all of this is done by GET requests. More precisely, the fragment identifier matches the following regexp:

```
(interval_type|graph_date_range)?chart_type=miles&interval_type=(week|month)&interval=[1-9]{6}&year_offset=[1-9]+
```

The first group doesn't seem to matter at all. Then, `interval_type` specifies whether to display weekly or monthly results. `interval` allows us to choose the date to display, using the format *YYYYMM* where *YYYY* is the year, and *MM* the month/week to display. Finally, `year_offset` isn't really useful. Thus, the GET request is fairly straightforward to make: I just have to choose a monthly display and iterate over the different months I want to monitor.

However, you can notice that while loading https://www.strava.com/pros/1603067#interval_type?interval=201802&interval_type=month&chart_type=miles&year_offset=0 (that is, the page that displays the runs of February 2018), the results of the current month are first displayed, and only *then* the results of February 2018. Thus, using `requests.get` always gives my the same page, no matter what fragment identifier I set.

My web browser must get a new web page after the first one (the one with the current month) is loaded, but how could I get it using Python ?

Comment: `requests` will only get the initial HTML page content, not any content subsequently loaded via JavaScript. There are endless duplicates here about web scraping sites with JS, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/8049520/3001761.

Comment: You have to find the URL where the page loads other stuff from, and make a request to it.

Comment: Can you share your current code, current and desired output?

Comment: @decadenza What is the best solution to do so ?